# how to Display Data php mysql premium to free member data

Tags: php, mysql

i hav two  table 'user_detail' and product table

```
  'user_detail' 
   id    email         membership
    1    x@gmail.com   Premium
    2    y@gmail.com   Free
    3    z@gmail.com   Free
    4    a@gmail.com   Premium
    5    c@gmail.com   Free

  'product' 
   id    email       Status    Catgory       Name   
    1    x@gmail.com Approved  Agriculture   Seed
    2    y@gmail.com Approved  Agriculture   Grain
    3    z@gmail.com Approved  Agriculture   Malt
    4    a@gmail.com Approved  Agriculture   Fruit
    5    c@gmail.com Approved  Mobile        iphone
```

tell me the query how i can aechive this goal i want to display result like this

Approved premium usr product show up and thn display free usr data 
means i want to c data like this

```
    id Membership   email       Status    Catgory       Name  
    1   premium   x@gmail.com Approved  Agriculture   Seed   
    4   premium   a@gmail.com Approved  Agriculture   Fruit   
    2   free      y@gmail.com Approved  Agriculture   Grain   
    3   free      z@gmail.com Approved  Agriculture   Malt    
    pls help me to sort my problm ...
```

Comment: This looks like a simple `JOIN` on the `email`

Comment: will u make the join query bcause im new in php mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can join both table on `email` column like

```
select ud.id,
ud.email,
p.Status,
p.Catgory,
p.Name,
ud.membership
from user_detail ud 
join product p on ud.email = p.email
order by ud.membership desc;
```

Comment: but i want to display product membership is premium then display free meber product

Comment: @machinegun, add a `order by` clause. See edit in answer. consider accepting the answer by cicking the check button if it helped.

Comment: SELECT * FROM user_detail ud join product p on p.product_status='Approved' AND p.Category='Agriculture' ORDER BY ud.user_detail_cMembership DESC

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM user_detail LEFT JOIN product ON product.email = user_detail.email;
```